# Building curl from sources - undefined reference to SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos

Tags: curl, build, openssl

I am not very experienced in those tools, so please bear with me. I want to build `curl` with SSL from sources. To do that I am also compiling `OpenSSL` from source.

After building and installing `OpenSSL` an archive is created the built files. This tar is then unpacked and should be used when building `curl`.

The way I did it is:

**OpenSSL**

```
./config shared -fPIC --prefix="/some/path/install_dir"
make depend
make && make install

rm -rf /some/path/install_dir/lib/pkgconfig
# create tar from $prefix/bin $prefix/include $prefix/lib
```

*pkgconfig is deleted, because when I left it there it contained absolute paths to the libraries on the openssl-building machine, which may be different from curl-building machines and I want to only use the ones from the archive. **I have no idea if this is a correct approach.***

**curl**

The archive from the previous step is copied and unpacked. Then

```
export LIBS='-ldl'
./configure --prefix="$(pwd)/<install_dir>" --with-ssl="<unpacked-tar>"
make && make install
```

However, `make` results in:

```
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get0_alpn_selected'
```

Building both openssl and curl on the same (testing) machine works.

Using `openssl-1.0.2g` and `curl-7.47.1`. Any idea what can be wrong?

---

**curl**'s config.log contains compile commands like this:

```
gcc -o conftest -O2 -Wno-system-headers  -I/home/teamcity/buildAgent/work/10199cb4c61825f3/openssl-1.0.2g/include -I/home/teamcity/buildAgent/work/10199cb4c61825f3/openssl-1.0.2g/include/openssl  -L/home/teamcity/buildAgent/work/10199cb4c61825f3/openssl-1.0.2g/lib conftest.c -lcrypto  -lz -lrt -ldl >&5
```

The **-I** folders are the ones I want to be included, so I think the systemwide libs should not be used.

Searching for `NPN` and `PROT` yielded no results, so the negotiation was not disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> The archive from the previous step is copied and unpacked
>   ...
>   Building both openssl and curl on the same (testing) machine works.

It sounds like OpenSSL on the build machine has Next Protocol Negotiation enabled, but the destination machine's OpenSSL was built *without* Next Protocol Negotiation. For OpenSSL 1.1.0, I believe that means the build machine was configured with `no-nextprotoneg`. For OpenSSL 1.0.2 and below, I believe that means it was configured with `no-npn`.

---

`SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos` is part of OpenSSL 1.1.0. The `.pod` is important because it means its documented, so its a public function meant to be called by user programs (this is a policy change for 1.1.0):

```
$ cd openssl-master
$ grep -IR SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos * | egrep '(ssl.h|.pod)'
doc/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb.pod:SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos, SSL_set_alpn_protos, SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb,
doc/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb.pod: int SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(SSL_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *protos,
doc/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb.pod:SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos() and SSL_set_alpn_protos() are used by the client to
doc/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb.pod:SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos() and SSL_set_alpn_protos() return 0 on success, and
include/openssl/ssl.h:__owur int SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(SSL_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *protos,
```

Its also available in 1.0.2:

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.2g
$ grep -IR SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos *
apps/s_client.c:        SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(ctx, alpn, alpn_len);
ssl/ssl.h:int SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(SSL_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *protos,
ssl/ssl_lib.c: * SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos sets the ALPN protocol list on |ctx| to |protos|.
ssl/ssl_lib.c:int SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(SSL_CTX *ctx, const unsigned char *protos,
ssl/ssltest.c:        SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(c_ctx, alpn, alpn_len);
util/ssleay.num:SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos                 387 EXIST::FUNCTION:
```

My guess is that cURL is using a downlevel, distro provided OpenSSL that lacks protocol negotiations (like OpenSSL 0.9.8):

```
export LIBS='-ldl'
./configure --prefix="$(pwd)/<install_dir>" --with-ssl="<unpacked-tar>"
make && make install
```

Check the `config.log` to see what cURL is finding during configuration.

---

You can disable protocol negotiations in OpenSSL with:

- OpenSSL 1.0.2 - `no-npn`
- OpenSSL 1.1.0 - `no-nextprotoneg`

It will show up in `<openssl/opensslconf.h`:

```
$ cd openssl-master
$ ./config no-nextprotoneg
...

$ find $PWD -name 'opensslconf.h'
.../include/openssl/opensslconf.h
$ cat .../include/openssl/opensslconf.h | grep PROT
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_NEXTPROTONEG
# define OPENSSL_NO_NEXTPROTONEG
```

And:

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.2g
$ ./config no-npn
...

$ cat include/openssl/opensslconf.h | grep NPN
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_NPN
# define OPENSSL_NO_NPN
# if defined(OPENSSL_NO_NPN) && !defined(NO_NPN)
#  define NO_NPN
```

So you should also verify it was not disabled at build time.

---

It looks like cURL is not completely sympathetic to `no-npn` and `no-nextprotoneg`:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
$ cd curl/
$ egrep -IR '(OPENSSL_NO_NPN|OPENSSL_NO_NEXTPROTONEG)' *
lib/vtls/openssl.c:    && !defined(OPENSSL_NO_NEXTPROTONEG)
```

That's also the only hit for `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos`:

```
$ grep -IR SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos *
lib/vtls/openssl.c:    SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos(connssl->ctx, protocols, cur)
```

Comment: Edited the question. Judging from config.log, it all looks as expected. Protocol negotiation does not look to be disabled